# replace column values of table if exists

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, sqlite

I have two table :

```
Main:

Id    | Count | Type
name1    3       1
name2    5       2
...

Temp:
Id     |Count|
name1     7
name3     2
```

I want to update `Count` column of `Main` table if `Id` exists in both table .

So after doing some operations result for above example should be :

```
Main:
Id    | Count | Type
name1    7       1
name2    5       2
```

My current code is :

```
QSqlQuery search_query = database_.exec("SELECT * From Temp");
while (search_query.next()){
    database_.exec("UPDATE Main"
        " SET Count=" + search_query.value(1).toString() +
        " WHERE Id = '" + search_query.value(0).toString() + "' ;");
}
database_.exec("DELETE FROM Temp");
```

It works fine but it's very slow !! (for 500 rows it take 2-3 minutes !!)

I'm looking for more efficient way . What should I do ?

Comment: You should use a `JOIN` and do the `UPDATE` in just one single statement. Btw do you use sqlite or MySQL or both?

Comment: @VMai I can use both of them

Comment: @omid - I recommend that before writing your SQL queries inline, try them in a query program first.  This way, you're not wasting time trying to figure out what works well using a C++ program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an UPDATE statement, you can look up new values with a correlated subquery:

```sql
UPDATE Main
SET Count = (SELECT Count FROM Temp WHERE Id = Main.Id)
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about calling a single update script to the database?

```
UPDATE Main m
INNER JOIN Temp t ON
    m.Id = t.Id
SET m.Count = t.Count
```

Comment: Ah I see. The idea was there. Your subquery should work just fine then :)